Как задать для определнного Layaout свой обработчик событий?
у меня  в коде меняется лайяут: (на другой, а активити лайяута)
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_setting)
И после этого кнопки внизу НавБара перестают работать
Вопрос: как создать для определнного лайяута свой обработчик событий?


                R.id.Setting -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "НАСТРОЙКИ ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_setting)
                    findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonSave)
                        .setOnClickListener{
                            //Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "ahahahhaahha ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
                        }

                    true
                }



если использую такой код, то:
fragment_setting открывается у меня
потом слушатель при нажатии на кнопку срабатывает
А потом мне надо вернуться на activity_main чтобы нижний тулбар заработал, а меня просто выкидывает из приложения если на активити меняю лайяут. А нижние кнопки на тулбаре не работают! (когда загружен fragment_setting )
И даже если для вновь открывшегося слоя делаю   tools:context=".MainActivity"> , то не реагирует ни нижний НавБар(на нажатие кнопок)

https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/transactions#add-remove

ругается на:  supportFragmentManager.commit {
replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment_settings)
setReorderingAllowed(true)
addToBackStack("name") // Name can be null
}. Вопрос : чем занменить ExampleFragment ?

это я из примера такой код беру
